# ERROR: ServiceError - Create environment operation is complete, but with errors. For more information, see troubleshooting documentation

Tags: django, deployment, dependencies, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, requirements.txt

I am trying to deploy Django app on AWS elasticbeanstalk and I am following the official document carefully https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html .but still I am getting an error when I run `eb create django-env` ,  which  first error saying `Instance deployment failed to install application dependencies. The deployment failed.` the bunch of errors follow(see the screenshot)
my folder structure seems alright and I have the requirements.txt in the root directory with all the dependency specified
I am using:

- Django==4.0.3
- my machine is Mac M1
- I have installed `awsebcli` on the venv and globally just on case

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you click on Logs, and then download the logs and look in the eb-engine.log for more information?

Comment: What littleforest means by "click on Logs" is to type in the terminal: "eb console" and then navigate on the left of the browser window that opens, to "logs" and download the file. An alternative is also to type, in the terminal: "eb logs" to view the logs.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and when I checked the eb logs, it showed that django was not installing because the latest version of django available is 3.2.13. You are running version 4.0.x. So you may want to downgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the exact same issue and it took me a while to understand this.
Apparently, EB doesn't support Django4.x versions. They are updated to 3.x.x versions only.

I assume you have updated the settings.py file with the host URL.

Downgrade Django and you can redeploy your application and it should work fine.